# Send multiple files using HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, httpclient, httparty

Here is the code which is working using `Net::HTTP::Post`

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
...
form_data = [
  ['attachments[]', File.open('file1.txt')],
  ['attachments[]', File.open('file2.txt')]
]
request.set_form form_data, 'multipart/form-data'
http.request(request)
```

Now, I am trying to use `httparty` like below but it is not working.

```
body = { attachments: [ File.open('file1.txt'), File.open('file2.txt') ] }

HTTParty.post(url, body: body)
```

The response I am getting from web service call is below:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x557d7b549f90 parsed_response={"error"=>true, "error_code"=>"invalid_attachment", "error_message"=>"Attachmen
t(s) not found or invalid."}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx"], "date"=>[
"Mon, 20 May 2019 07:41:50 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "content-length"=>["102"], "connection"=>["close"], "vary"=>["
Authorization"], "set-cookie"=>["c18664e1c22ce71c0c91742fbeaaa863=uv425hihrbdatsql1udrlbs9as; path=/"], "expires"=>["Thu, 19 Nov 1981
08:52:00 GMT", "-1"], "cache-control"=>["no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "private, must-revalidate"], "pragma"=>["no-cache", "no
-cache"], "x-ratelimit-limit"=>["60"], "x-ratelimit-remaining"=>["59"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=63072000; includeSubdom
ains;"]}>
```

It looks like it is not able to read the contents of files. Does `HTTParty` support this or I need to use some other gem?

Comment: Can you post full backtrace errors?  Are you sure the url you're hitting is valid?

Comment: did you try, form_data = [
  ['attachments[0]', File.open('file1.txt')],
  ['attachments[1]', File.open('file2.txt')]
]

Comment: is it possible the files have bad data or formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, I just tested it, worked for me no problem.

```
HTTParty.post(url, 
              body: { attachments: [ 
                   File.read('foo.txt'), 
                   File.read('bar.txt')] })
```

Comment: multipart is used as content-type automatically

Comment: right... i removed the option and updated.  Not sure what the problem is, sounds like something on the server side.

Comment: @RajkaranMishra, i tried this way, its working, did you fixed your issue by this Answer?

Comment: when i sent image file using this, then it shows me unsupported media files.

Answer (score 0):

With HTTParty you can pass IO/Files as parameters the same way (multipart is automatically set to true if there's a file in parameters).

But keep in mind that files should be closed after upload, otherwise you may run out of file descriptors before GC collects them:

```rb
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'].map{|fname| File.open(fname) }
begin
  HTTParty.post(url, body: { attachments: files })
ensure
  files.each(&:close)
end
```

That should work for you if net/http variant does (and is actually the same as your code).

Other thing to look at is content type detection by filename - because file upload consists of filename, content type and data itself.
Error 400 with "invalid_attachment" you're getting suggests that more probably it's related to content type or other validation on server side (so make sure you're testing with the same files and nothing else changes other than http lib), also check httparty to be a recent version

Answer (score 0):

I've written a test program which sends the same multipart request using both `Net::HTTP` and `HTTParty`. Then it compares and prints the request strings so that we can compare them. The only substantive difference between the two requests is that HTTParty attempts to guess and set the `Content-Type` header (e.g. `text/plain` for a file named *file1.txt*), whereas Net::HTTP always uses `application/octet-stream`.

HTTParty definitely does read the files and send them in the request. So, I suggest you investigate if the server is returning an error due to the `Content-Type` (maybe the content type in your particular request is not supported).

For your reference, here is the [test program and specific results](https://github.com/applandinc/land-of-applets/tree/master/send-multiple-files-using-httparty_56190082).